# How is working with IOT project being viewed in software industry?

Tags: projects

I an working in a project company that does projects for government. My previous experience was in web mainly dealing with React, Vue and NodeJS. Today I was just approached by my boss to consider for an opportunity to work for an IOT project with gov side. There will be mainly javascript front end and some java backend (no experience in java). I recalled I did some research before and found out that IOT software engineers are generally worse off than those web engineers. Not too sure whether I will be hitting the right ground if I say yes to my boss. Any opinion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "worse off"? Do you mean salary?

Comment: I cant really recall what I have read.. Could be salary wise or in general..

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting your salary data, but I know a few people who work on IoT and ML (edge inference etc, currently a very hot area), and they're paid *much* more than a typical web engineer.

Comment: But if you're writing a JavaScript frontend you're still acting as a web developer, and IoT is just the business area of your project more than technology. It's like asking "are web developers worse off than fintech developers" - those are two different facets of your job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IoT project will be viewed great if you are applying to an IoT company, but not great if you are applying to be a COBOL mainframe engineer. The "software industry" is too broad to hold one view on a technology.

Do you want to learn more java, javascript and embedded systems? Then join the IoT project. A javascript frontend and java backend describes most commercial commercial web apps, so those skills will be easily translatable.

However, if that sounds boring to you then pick something else, but just trying to pick a technology/business area that you think others will view well is going to make an unhappy career.

Since you said you don't know what it would entail, I would say go for it. It's often better to work in some area, decide you don't like it and leave rather than just wait for the perfect thing. If you don't like it you can always leave.